# Web application authentication over multiple subdomains

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, web, spring-security

We're developing a web based application using spring-mvc and spring-security.

Simply put this application will have a website running on the main domain, foo.com

foo.com will just be a pretty shell that will get it's data (using javascript) from api.foo.com which will be our REST API.

api.foo.com will also be used by the mobile applications that will be developed and will make use of OAuth 2 for it's authentication flow.

When a user is logged in on foo.com he will be authenticated using a cookie based system.

We're wondering what would be a good solution to let that already logged in used make use of api.foo.com in an authenticated way ?

Should the cookie be re-used and sent with every request ? We've read that cookies + CORS don't play well on different domains is that true for subdomains ?

We've also been thinking about letting the cookie based logged in user use OAuth , behind the scenes, to access api.foo.com. 
So when a user has authenticated himself a access token will be given to the javascript code that will use that same token to identifiy itself at api.foo.com

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar framework, but we are using HMAC for API authorization.  I would imagine you could use a code in the cookie in a similar fashion. HMAC is like OAuth light, but it may be perfect for this situation.

Here are some links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code
http://massimilianosciacco.com/implementing-hmac-authentication-rest-api-spring-security

Comment: Thanks, the HMAC method is new to me. After reading about it I was wondering how I could store this private key on the client side safely within a browser ?